# GUI programming c++ or c#

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface

I am taking software engineering classes at my university. I just took data structures and i am almost done taking design patterns. With the design patterns class the instructor let us choose what Language to use and what IDE to use on our labs. Since, i know C++ mostly i used that. Most of the class used c# and some used java..

Well, i just signed up for GUI programming spring term, and its the same teacher, and he said we can use whatever we like. Since, i have never really used C# i might be better of using c++? I have looked into using QT4 but i dont know how hard it is, and how much helps really out there? Since, there wont be much lecturing..

I am considering using C# since i have taken classes in VB.NET and have used winforms quite a bit. However, i would love to use C++ what are your thoughts? Is c++ gui something i might use in the future in the real world? or am i better off trying to learn C#
I would love to stick with C++ in my career path though..

I dont want to be stuck learning C# and GUI at the same time either. 
Is QT4 a good way to go?

Comment: It is pointless to use C++ to program GUI code.  But that's not the point, you are there to learn something.  Which makes the language the underlying API was targeting probably the best choice.  Gets you straight to the point without layers to obfuscate the way it really operates.  Which I assume is C.

Comment: Great. Another question for a bunch of people to provide their uninformed and poorly substantiated opinions about how MFC sucks. Not really interested in *that* again.

Comment: @David: Not *everything* about it, but yeah I suppose. The only compelling arguments I hear against it is that you still have to learn Win32. I don't really understand why that's bad. I felt like I had to learn that to do just about anything in WinForms, too. I think MFC makes me a little faster than if I were writing directly to Win32. I tried Qt to see what all the fuss was about, but it's just not native enough for me. I promptly uninstalled it, got about 300 GB back and much smaller executables as well. I suppose WTL is a +1 over MFC, but certainly not enough to justify the hatred.

Comment: @cody I find mfc hard to fathom but I'm used to vcl

Comment: @David: I've never used it. If you know straight Win32, I'm not sure why MFC is difficult to follow. It just handles the simple, common stuff for you. I just don't think I could give up Visual Studio for a Borland product. I've never found them terribly impressive, but that's probably as dogmatic as the people who hate MFC for no good reason. Regardless, it's a big difference to say "I am not experienced with that GUI toolkit" vs "That GUI toolkit sucks, no one should ever use it, it's the spawn of satan" like I hear about MFC. It's tiring.

Comment: @Cody Did you ever use early versions of Visual Studio? They were very easy to give up!!

Comment: @Cody: If ever you need more portability, you might want to give wxWidgets a try. It uses the platform's native GUI API. The libary installer for windows is only 11MB, and the API lines itself more towards the Win32/MFC API (from what I've read).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

qt is not that difficult to work with. I have tried some gui tool kits for c++ and this is my experience in terms of c++

## Qt

For c++ development and gui's i would overwhelmingly favour Qt instead of alternative libraries like win32 api, Microsoft foundation classes, etc.

#### Advantages

- qt is cross platform and can be used on windows, linux, symbian, windows ce, mac osx
- qt is not that difficult to learn. If you understand the basics of c++ classes and some template programming
- qt is used to professionally create guis. I don't recall exactly but i think autodesk maya and adobe photoshop may be using qt for their gui's
- qt4 has more than just gui programming ie it has libraries for networking, internationalisation, phonon for video and audio, animation framework, etc etc

#### Disadvantages

- it's not a native library so your application would be larger than if you used win32 api but even then i still think its smaller than .net run time

#### To start learning qt now

- find the book c++ gui programming using qt4 second edition. or another good resource
- download the qt sdk for visual studio 2008
- download the qt visual studio addin for visual studio 2008
- create a new qt4 project and compile and run your first project

## C#

i should state from the outset that i am not a c# developer but i know it has some good stuff

#### Known advantages

- allows you to use windows forms, wpf, linq (language integrated query) etc
- wpf is what you would be most interested in as a c# developer

#### Disadvantages

- like all .net languages, it is still slower than native applications made in c++
- not portable to different operating systems like mac osx, linux(But remember MOST USERS (90%) ARE RUNNING WINDOWS)
- If you target users of windows xp, you would have to inconvenience them with having to download .net in order for your application to work. To me this is the biggest disadvantage of .net languages since most users i know have slow internet connections

#### To start learning gui development using c#

- find the book windows presentation foundation unleashed or any good c#/ wpf book

#### Warning

- i am not an expert in c++ or c# and am just giving my opinion or experience.
- i have limited experience in c#

Comment: I downloaded and installed both the SDK and the VS addin. How do i use QT with VS? Do i use the QT creator to create the apps?

Comment: If you are used to working in visual studio, there is no need to change to qt creator. Besides the download size becomes bigger if you are using qt creator. Personally i just use the sdk only with visual studio for the simple reason that am used to working in visual studio. I wil post you a link on how to get started. For now you can check out the examples provided with the sdk to see the possibilities

Comment: Good answer, but one thing to add: C# has a really good GUI designer for Winforms, much better than anything I have seen in the QT world, and much better than the one for WPF. So if you are going to create a Winforms application, C# is definitely a better choice than C++.

Comment: @icelated : check out http://qtcrashcourse.blogspot.com/2011/02/this-blog-explains-how-you-can-quickly.html

Comment: Deo- thanks a bunch- i have been playing around with the creator and reading tutorials. I am starting to understand how QT works.

Comment: @Doc Brown. I agree. If you want to use winforms, c# is easier to use than managed c++ (the so called c++/CLI)

Comment: There's a C#/dotNET clone that supports Windows/Linux/Mac: The Mono framework (http://www.mono-project.com). (I've never used it, nor Microsoft's.)

Comment: @DrDeo: Your c# disadvantages aren't exactly correct.  As Emile pointed out Mono is cross platform (http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).  Second, with regards to XP; the .net framework is shipped with XP by some OEMs like Dell and Gateway.  Regardless, it's included in Vista and 7 automatically and will be for the foreseable future.

Comment: @Emile, @Chris -- Mono doesn't support WPF, nor does it currently plan to.

Answer (score 5):

> I am considering using C# since i have taken classes in VB.NET and have used winforms quite a bit. However, i would love to use C++ what are your thoughts?

If you want to use Windows Forms, and C++, then you might use C++/CLI  (formerly known as Managed C++).  This uses extensions to C++ to support .NET, and is the only .NET language that allows mixed CLI and native code, so once you glued you interface code to your application code, you can use ISO C++ exclusively.

That said except where I have been implementing an interface for existing C++ code, I have found it easier to simply learn C# which is designed from the ground-up to be a .NET language so is generally a much more comfortable fit.

In the ISO C++ arena, choices include Qt and WxWidgets, both of which are cross-platform and well supported by books and on-line information and communities.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [WxWidgets](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_Compared_To_Other_Toolkits) before (C++). It's easy and fun. Afaik, a significant amount of UI design is done with design editors or various XML/LUA importers, so the toolkit you use essentially doesn't really matter, because the event-driven code you will write will be very similar for almost everything.

The WxWidgets tutorials are great and the forums are helpful. If you're wondering how WxWidgets compares to other Toolkits, they have a [great wiki page dedicated to it](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_Compared_To_Other_Toolkits)

Answer (score 1):

Another question whose responses can be debated for time eternity. From my experience, I would say both languages have equally mature toolkits for creating user interfaces.

Hence for any project it only depends on what would be your preference. Generally, developing a UI using .NET is easier due to the fantastic RAD support provided by Visual Studio which unfortunately does not provide that level of sophistication for C++ based projects.

Having said that keep in mind that user interfaces exist on all operating systems; not just Windows. Hence you should focus on the basic tenets of GUI programming and treat the language only as a means of putting your thoughts into execution.

Hence if you really wanna do UI programming across all platforms; then C++ is the best bet ( of course these days you have Mono but not sure if they have a QT based toolkit you are looking at).

Quite a mouthful - but to make it short:
It is all about your choice and learning. If you wanna learn C# and use it go ahead. But if you are comfortable with C++, you can still use it and there is nothing that can be done in C# but cannot be done using C++.

Comment: In the second paragraph you compare .NET with C++ like .NET was a language - which it is not.  Also, in VS, C++/CLI *is* a .NET language with no less sophisticated support than any other .NET language (in fact it is the most powerful and flexible - and possibly dangerous - of .NET languages since it allows CLI and native code to be mixed).

Comment: Yep that's right. By .NET I actually intended to mean C#.And you are right about C++ CLI :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I couldn't possibly give a better answer than Dr.Deo, but I can share my bit. I used to do a lot of GUI programming before (more than 5 years ago, with Borland's VCL in either Delphi or C++). I recently had to produce a GUI for a little project, so I went for Qt4. I was able to almost entirely finish the GUI in one day without any prior knowledge of Qt4 (of course, it was a simple, one-window GUI). I found it very easy to use and quick to learn. If you have any GUI experience at all, it will be very intuitive. As for C++ knowledge required, it's minimal. You have to be comfortable with a fair dose of inheritance and polymorphism, but that is very typical of GUI tools and it really is just basic C++ knowledge of OOP.

I think several people have already made the point about being cross-platform. This will be more and more important in the future as alternatives to Windows are becoming mainstream (basically all the people I work with either have a Mac or run a distro of Linux) and as more in-between phone and tablet-PC products are emerging.

And, anyways, the language you use for programming a GUI isn't really that important, it is the tool-set. I think Qt4 is very complete. It also save you the trouble of interfacing to your existing code (let alone learning C#). Finally, Qt4 is very nicely usable with any IDE or build system (if you don't want to switch your code to qmake and/or Qt-Creator).

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on what you are trying to learn.

If you want to learn about how GUI libraries work as opposed to how to use them then you want to look at plain Win32.

If you want to learn how to use them then you'll find C# or VB with WinForms the easiest to pick up. And of course they let you use a great designer.

Don't worry about issues like cross platform whilst you are learning the basics! You should focus on learning principles rather than specifics.

Answer (score 1):

As @David Heffernan said, don't worry about cross platform unless you must have it (premature optimization).  There is a price to pay for that flexibility that most cross platform kits offer.  Further, from my years of experience as both a developer and a user, native platform toolkits generally offer a better end user experience (often less surprises about what and how the user is allowed and not allowed to do with each control or surface).

In a learning environment, you want to consider what you hope to accomplish in a semester.  A typical three month overall semester schedule with successive milestones suggests you'll want low friction.  Learning a gui library can be an excellent achievement, but you'll probably want some basic familiarity with at least the environment or context before you get started in order to actually complete the intermediate tasks in a timely manner: presumably interactions and otherwise general user experience are at the core of the class' focus.

For these reasons, I would consider sticking with c++, as you have a sense for the paradigm and fundamentals of the language and tools.  But, because it is a learning environment, I would strongly consider something less mainstream, but ripe with potential in the library.  I might look at hardware accelerated windowing libraries, either OpenGl based xgl if targeting unix/linux, or Windows Presentation Foundation if targeting Windows.

Answer (score -3):

For GUI programming you could go for Visual C++.

It's hard to code everything in VC++ so people go for MFC. 
MFC provides 100s of classes that make life much easier. So all you need to do is learn the basics of VC++ and learn MFC.

Comment: MFC has become antiquated, and should only be used for legacy projects. Not to mention that it's not portable outside of Windows. The OP would be better off with QT or dotNET.

Comment: @Emile: How does something "become antiquated"? What does that mean? By what process does it take place? Who is responsible for antiquating it? How do you judge that something is antiquated? And perhaps even more importantly, how is MFC *more* antiquated than WinForms?

Comment: Though I did, for those same reason.

Comment: @John If you delete this post you'll get your lost reputation back, and you'll win a badge called peer pressure. Just wanted to let you know!

Comment: @Emile Why do you think that a student needs to be concerned with GUI portability? You don't learn well by trying to take on all possible considerations at once. Learning works by layering knowledge on top of good foundations.

Comment: @David: The library (namely, QT) takes on all considerations at once, not the user. Those multiple considerations are abstracted away by the library. I figure if you're going to invest time learning a GUI library, it might as well be one that doesn't lock you into a particular platform.

Comment: @Emile My point is that a student should be trying to learn the principles, not a particular library. I'm actually a big fan of Qt.

Comment: @Cody: By antiquated, I meant no longer fashionable. Hardly anyone is developing new projets based on MFC. Even Microsoft no longer actively promotes it. If a student is going to learn a GUI library, better for it to be a libary that's widely used, so that the student may more easily get help.

Comment: @David: I understand that the student will learn the same principles (GUI programming), whether it be MFC or QT. But the student might as well kill two birds with one stone by learning a library that has not become "antiquated". Consider this analogy: Would you recommend that a student learn x86 assembler over the assembler for some obscure machine no longer in use? The student will learn about microprocessors either way.

Comment: @Emile I don't disagree with that. I'd just argue that one shouldn't let cross-platform and portability issues dominate the decision process. The choice should be based on what will produce the best learning environment. That's the point I was trying to get across with my answer.

Comment: @David: Gotcha. :-) I'd be curious to know which GUI library would be considered the best for learning puposes. Seems to me like they all operate in the same fundamental way: A hierarchy of widgets and a message queueing system for events.

Comment: @Emile I guess it depends what you are trying to learn. If you wanted someone to have enough knowledge to write custom components then I'd want them to learn quite low-level, e.g. native Win32, WndProc, message queue. If you wanted them to be consumers of GUI libraries then something like WinForms, Qt, VCL. I agree that they are all basically the same. But if you want to get to the metal then you need to move the heavy frameworks out of the way.