# Qt C++ Minimum size of resizable rectangle

Tags: c++, qt

In my application I have rectangle which I can resize (manually implemented mouse events for resizing). My problem is that I can resize my rectangle in any size. How can I implement function which forbids to resize under 100x100 pixels. In other words I want function which sets minimum size for rectangle so user can't resize that rectangle under 100x100 pixels. If needed I will provide parts of mine code, but for now I need idea or pseudo code.

Comment: please read document about sizeHint

Comment: here is a nice article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553304/help-needed-to-understand-form-layout-mechanisms-in-qt

Comment: Thanks but rectangle doesn't have sizeHint and I resize rectangle by mouse, it's size is not affected by size of other components or mainwindow

Comment: how about resizeEvent?

Comment: add the size constraint in the mouseevent, where you are calculating the rectangle size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already written the code, which resizes your rectangle, all you need to add is something like this:

```
QRect r = oldRect();
switch (border)
{
    case Left:
        r.setLeft(newLeftPos());
        if (r.width() < minimumWidth())
            r.setLeft(r.right() - minimumWidth());
    break;

    ...

}
draw(r);
```

Comment: What's the Left case. Is that case when I move left side of rectangle?

Comment: Exactly. The same code should be written for all other sides (and corners, if you want to) of the rectangle.

Comment: Thank you, your idea is perfect for my application