# Qt How to change gridlayout column size

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer, qtgui

Suppose I have a gridlayout of three columns. I want each column to have custom width. Seems to me that the width of the columns are fixed automatically.

How can I do this in the qt designer?

Comment: To set size column You can use `setColumnMinimumWidth()`, but You also must manipulate `setSizePolicy` for each element in column as QLabel, QGroupBox etc, because policy determines how behavior must be particular object in column.  Look Here http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsizepolicy.html also probably find some here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553304/understanding-form-layout-mechanisms-in-qt

Comment: So without the manual tweaking, with the help of GUI(in qtDesigner) the individual column widths cannot be changed? :/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the QT Designer (GUI)

1. First, use the Grid Layout widget (say, you want 3 column)
2. Second, in the Property Editor, choose the layoutColumnStretch and enter value (such as 200,100,100)

Result: 1st column 200px, 2nd column 100px, 3rd column 100px,